# nmake / VC++ 2010 : Compile without MSVCR100.dll depends

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, nmake

Is there any nmake option for compiling Visual C++ 2010 without the output dll or exe depends on the MSVCR100.dll ?

Comment: Only use /MT with dlls when you *really* know why you shouldn't.

Answer (score 4):

/MT compiler switch is used to statically link to CRT. You should add it to compiler options inside your makefile.

Answer (score 0):

[Link to Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11618650/how-to-not-link-against-msvcr100-dll)

> with project settings, not with compiler keys.
>   To do this, go to C/C++ Properties -> Code Generation and under Runtime Library select Multi-threaded (/MT) or Multi-threaded Debug (/MTd) from the drop-down.